# Installing oci8 driver: (pecl install oci8) Oracle Instant Client SDK header files not found (Mac OSX High Sierra)

Tags: php, oracle, oci8, instantclient

I need to install the oci8 driver for MacOSX (High Sierra). However, whenever I run the command pecl install oci8, I get asked.

Please provide the path to the ORACLE_HOME directory. Use 'instantclient,/path/to/instant/client/lib' if you're compiling with Oracle Instant Client [autodetect].

I respond with  'instantclient, /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2' and

```
building in /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-aneakellOvIf6k/oci8-2.2.0
running: /private/tmp/pear/temp/oci8/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/opt/php/bin/php-config --with-oci8='instantclient, /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2'
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.5
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.5/include/php -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.5/include/php/main -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.5/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.5/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.5/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.5/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.5/pecl/20180731
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.5/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... re2c
checking for re2c version... 1.1.1 (ok)
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking for Oracle Database OCI8 support... yes, shared
checking PHP version... 7.3.5, ok
checking OCI8 DTrace support... no
checking size of long int... 8
checking checking if we're on a 64-bit platform... yes
checking Oracle Instant Client directory...  /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2
checking Oracle Instant Client SDK header directory... configure: error: Oracle Instant Client SDK header files not found
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/oci8/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/opt/php/bin/php-config --with-oci8='instantclient, /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2'' failed
```

is the output.

I have tried downloading the oci8.2.2.0.zip online and manually configuring without pecl. However, this did not prove successful.

Currently, my /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2 looks like this:

```
-r-xr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel        342 Apr 24  2015 glogin.sql
-r--r--r--@ 1 root  wheel    4036257 Dec 13  2016 ojdbc8.jar
-r--r--r--@ 1 root  wheel      74230 Jan 26  2017 xstreams.jar
-r-xr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel    8179072 Jun 28  2017 libnnz12.dylib
-r-xr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel    1639388 Jul 12  2017 libsqlplusic.dylib
-r-xr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel     151748 Aug  8  2017 libocijdbc12.dylib
-r-xr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel     237780 Jan  8  2018 libons.dylib
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 root  wheel    1267088 Jan  9  2018 libsqlplus.dylib
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 root  wheel      84988 Jan  9  2018 liboramysql12.dylib
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 root  wheel    1465312 Jan  9  2018 libocci.dylib.12.1
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 root  wheel    4685408 Jan  9  2018 libclntshcore.dylib.12.1
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 root  wheel   85621532 Jan  9  2018 libclntsh.dylib.12.1
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 root  wheel  124769196 Jan  9  2018 libociei.dylib
-rw-rw-rw-@ 1 root  wheel        400 Jan  9  2018 BASIC_README
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 root  wheel     146084 Jan  9  2018 uidrvci
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 root  wheel      40360 Jan  9  2018 genezi
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 root  wheel      10036 Jan  9  2018 adrci
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel       8480 Jan  9  2018 sqlplus
-rw-rw-rw-@ 1 root  wheel        404 Jan  9  2018 SQLPLUS_README
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel         20 Jun 12 15:36 libclntsh.dylib -> libclntsh.dylib.12.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel         18 Jun 12 15:36 libocci.dylib -> libocci.dylib.12.1
drwxrwxrwx@ 8 root  wheel        256 Jun 12 15:53 sdk
```

Comment: The first thing to try is to remove the space after the comma in 'instantclient, /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2'  Personally I would (and do) use Instant Client 18 instead of 12.2.  Both connect to the same range of database versions.

Comment: OMG!!!!!! I was trapped on this for 5 days.... Oracle should be smart enough to put in their program a way to remove the spaces themselves ....

Comment: Had a similar problem, in my case I was downloading the instant client, but not downloading optional development SDK. I found [here](https://medium.com/@evenstensberg/apache-and-php-with-oci8-oracle-instant-client-in-mac-osx-100343970159) that I need to download both instantclient and sdk and unzip to same folder. After this `pecl install oci8` worked for me